# Yii2. Вход и регистрация на одной странице

Tags: yii2, view, model

На странице есть две кнопки: вход и регистрация. При нажатии по каждой выскакивает соответствующее модальное окно. Как в данной ситуации объединить две модели в одной view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так же как делали бы с одной, добавляете вторую модель, переименовываете и отвравляете на представление, к примеру вот так:

```
public function actionLogin()
{
    if (!\Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        return $this->goHome();
    }

    $loginModel = new LoginForm();
    $signupModel = new SignupForm();
    if ($loginModel->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $loginModel->login()) {
        //Ваша логика
        return $this->goBack();
    } else {
        return $this->render('login', [
            'loginModel' => $loginModel,
            'signupModel' => $signupModel
        ]);
    }
}
```

При самбите /login данные будут идти в этот же метод, при signup будет идти на метод signup, там ничего менять не надо, но это абстрактный пример, т.к. не вижу вашего кода могу предположить что он похож на стандартный.